# Can't convert to xml from string created by concatenation

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I have the following code in order to convert a string to xml document :

```
var str = "<b1> content </b1> <b2> content2 </b2>";
var xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
```

It works fine like that but when I create my string by concatenating it doesn't work. I have a parseerror.

```
var str = "<b1> content </b1>"; str += "<b2> content2 </b2>";
var xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
```

Do you know why it can't do it ?

Comment: Is this a simplified example? the latter works fine as is.

Answer (score 0):

I got this situation before  and the problem was DOMParser Only one root element is allowed
you can try to make it like that

```
var parseDom = function(str){
   str = '<root>' + str + '</root>';
   return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
}

var str = "<b1> content </b1>"; str += "<b2> content2 </b2>";
var xml = parseDom(str);
```